# Can I use XPath to filter elements by CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, css, xpath

Or do I have to do something like this:

```
var nodes = document.childNodes;
for (var i in nodes) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(nodes[i], null).getPropertyValue('someproperty') == 'somevalue')
        // do stuff
}
```

**Edit:**

I'm not very familiar with XPath. A 'simple' stab at the problem would be something like this:

```
function test() {
    var resultSet = document.evaluate("//*[@float='left']", document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (var i = 0; i < resultSet.snapshotLength; i++) {
        var element = resultSet.snapshotItem(i);
        alert(element);
    }
}
```

But unsurprisingly this doesn't work, since `float` is a property, not an attribute...

Comment: Can you give an example of code? You can certainly search inside the style attribute.

Comment: Viet: could you give me an example of how to do that in XPath? For instance http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example4.html doesn't say anything about searching within the style attribute.

Comment: oops, that link was supposed to be http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Viet & knut said before, you can go ahead with attribute selectors & string matching functions: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#string.

You should not confuse XPath with Javascript :)

I have hint for you. Say you have a node:

```
<a href="http://google.com" style="padding: 10px; float: left; margin: 10px auto;">Look at me!</a>
```

Use `fn:substring-after("padding: 10px; float: left;", "float:")` to get the `" left; margin: 10px auto;"`.

And then use `fn:substring-before(" left; margin: 10px auto;", ";")` to get the `" left"`.

After this, use `fn:normalize-space(" left")` to get `"left"` :)

Comment: I think the Javascript method is more elegant compared to this. Nonetheless, thanks for answering the question!

Comment: Yes indeed, but this was what you were asking for. I only use XPath when I don't have JS engine.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/

Comment: I believe this selects for attributes, not style properties. Also, I'd prefer a native Javascript solution, and Javascript doesn't have CSS selector support built-in.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Sorry about that. You may use the computed style.

Comment: oops. Actually my first code snippet was meant to use getComputedStyle, but I left that function call out. Yep aside from that your link is functionally equivalent to what I originally posted... I guess there's really no better way.